# Timeline Seekbar in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, seekbar

I'm trying a flash actionscript project to include a custom seekbar for timeline frame navigation. Now i could get dragger moving across the seekbar with respect to the totalframes. But dragging the seekbar brings error. Also i want to include timer to show the minute and seconds passed.

```
var ratio = 0; 
ratio = this.totalFrames/main.line.width;
var go = 0;
var isComplete = false;
var tFrame = this.totalFrames;
var isPress = false;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, drag);
function drag(event:Event):void {   
if(main.dragger.x<=main.line.width){
    main.dragger.x = this.currentFrame/ratio;
}
}

main.dragger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag1);
 function drag1(event:MouseEvent):void {    
  main.dragger.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(0, 9.2, main.line.width, 9.2));
  isPress = true;
  main.dragger.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frame);
}

function frame(event:Event):void
{
    trace (this.currentFrame);
    if(this.currentFrame < tFrame){
        gotoAndPlay(Math.round(main.x*ratio));
    }else{
        gotoAndPlay(tFrame-1);
    }

}
main.dragger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,release);

function release(event:MouseEvent):void {
  main.dragger.stopDrag();
  main.dragger.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag1);
}
```

when i click the dragger to move, it automatically jumps to starting position and also the gotoAndPlay jumps to that position and continuously stays there..

Attachment:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4UOEUQTrhB0a21EaUpaUE52MGM

**UPDATE**
This is an other method found in adobe forum, But this also gives the same dragging problem.

```
var tl:MovieClip=this;
tl.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterframeF);

paramF(tl,1,0,tl.totalFrames,slider.line.width);  // create a horizontal slider movieclip that contains a track movieclip and a thumbscroll movieclip that do the obvious and have left-sided reg point
paramF(slider,0,1,slider.line.width-slider.thumbscroll.width,tl.totalFrames);
var scrollRect1:Rectangle=new Rectangle(0,0,slider.line.width-slider.thumbscroll.width,0);

function enterframeF(e:Event):void{
slider.thumbscroll.x=tl.m*tl.currentFrame+tl.b;
}

slider.thumbscroll.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,scrolldownF);
slider.thumbscroll.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,scrollupF);

function scrolldownF(e:MouseEvent):void{
tl.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterframeF);
slider.thumbscroll.startDrag(false,scrollRect1);
slider.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,scrollF);
}
function scrollupF(e:MouseEvent):void{
tl.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterframeF);
slider.thumbscroll.stopDrag();
slider.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,scrollF);
}
function scrollF(e:MouseEvent):void{
tl.gotoAndStop(Math.round(slider.thumbscroll.x*slider.m+slider.b));
}


function paramF(mc:MovieClip,x1:Number,y1:Number,x2:Number,y2:Number):void{
mc.m=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
mc.b=y2-mc.m*x2;
}
```

Comment: The question is to broad. You are basically asking someone to figure out what you are doing in your code and to fix a solution for you. What error are you getting? Have you investigated, why? With your effort applied, looking at the source files should not be required.

Comment: when i click the dragger to move, it automatically jumps to starting position and also the gotoAndPlay jumps to that position and continuously stays there..